# I want to create and update UserProfile object with OneToOne User object field and create a api in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new in Django rest framework, I tried my whole day but can't do it,I want to do full crud operation in my UserProfile Model which have a OneToOne field user, User can only update their own profile and in UserProfile create or update user shouldn't update User[username], How can i achieve it Please Help me

*** serializers.py ***

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from product.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['username','password', ]
        

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = "__all__"
        
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user_instance = User.objects.get(
            username=user_data['username'])
        user_instance.save()
        
        user_profile_instance = UserProfile.objects.create(
            **validated_data, user=user_instance)
        user_profile.save()
        return user_profile
```

*** views.py ***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .serializers import  UserProfileSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from product.models import UserProfile

# Create your views here.

class CreateUserView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return UserProfile.objects.filter(user = user)
```

*** models.py ***

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='India')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 0):

For Authentication you can use token based authentication(like jwt)
and for username you can use read_only=True
no need to send the password for get request
to update profile you need to handle put/post methods

Comment: User is already created, I want to create UserProfile object with User OneToOne field and user should only update their own profile, can you please tell me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

CLEANED Serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['username','password']
    

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # REMOVED all unecessary overrides
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = "__all__"
```

Views:

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                         mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    # Changed inherited class and class NAME !
    # I assume that your endpoint is something like /users/me/profile
    # I think you want only to update user profile
    # Listing or creating profile here is bad - user should have only ONE profile
    # and you should do this on user model post_save signal

    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.user_profile
```

This setup will allow you to update profile and only profile data

In your models file you can make signal listener for automatically creating UserProfile object on User object create.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```